# String concatenation in join clause

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have been having some issue with adding some string concatenation in my LINQ JOIN condition and its translation in Oracle sql query. This used to work fine on our legacy solution that was using EF.
Let's take the following example:

```
var query = (from sub in connection.InvoiceSubStatuses
                     join lab in connection.Litteral
                     on "STN_ASP_PIE_STATUT_EXTERNE[" + sub.StatusCode + "]" + "{" + vendorId + "}" equals lab.Code
                     where   sub.IsFlaggedDelete == 0
                     select new InvoiceSubStatusDTO
                     {
                         Description = lab.Libelle,
                         StatusCode = sub.StatusCode,
                         Id = sub.Id,
                         Culture = lab.Culture,
                         StatusType = sub.StatusType

                     });
```

This is interpreted as the following sql code:

```
SELECT "l".LIBELLE "Description", "s".CODE_STATUSFAC "StatusCode", "s".SYS_ID "Id", "l".CULTURE "Culture", "s".TYPE_STATUSFAC "StatusType"
FROM STATUSFAC "s"
INNER JOIN LITTERAUX "l" ON N'STN_ASP_PIE_STATUT_EXTERNE[' || COALESCE("s".CODE_STATUSFAC, N'') || N']' || N'{' || TO_NCHAR(:p__vendorId_0) || N'}' = "l".CODE
WHERE ("s".DIGITAL_LETTER = 1) AND ("s".SYS_FLAG_DEL = 0)
```

This causes an error , as Oracle doesn't allow 'N' text literal inside COALESCE (   COALESCE("s".CODE_STATUSFAC, **N**'')). If I manually change it to COALESCE("s".CODE_STATUSFAC, ''), the query works fine, but I don't know how to resolve this from Linq.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a workaround?Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug in EF Core Oracle provider. Update to latest or create issue, probably [here](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues).

Comment: Try `new { Code = "STN_ASP_PIE_STATUT_EXTERNE[" + sub.StatusCode + "]" + "{" + vendorId + "}" } equals new { lab.Code }`.

Comment: @GertArnold, same issue, unfortunately .

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, we are using Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore, I guess I should create there the issue?

Comment: @AnaMunteSPB, definitely yes. You should create issue in Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore repository.

Comment: Another try: `from sub in connection.InvoiceSubStatuses.Select(s => new { ..., Code = "..." + s.etc.  }) join lab in connection.Litteral on sub.Code equals lab.Code`.

Comment: @GertArnold, same it still adds the Coalesce with N text literal

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was coming from the fact that the column in the DB in non-nullable, so when trying to do a string concatenation, the Oracle provider adds the COALESCE . So in order to bypass this , I added the attribute [Required] on the column StatusCode .

Comment: Well, it is workaround. Don't forget to create issue.

Comment: Yes, I am planning on it. I just need to find the right place to put the bug,since DevArt's solution is not on github